# How to compare two PCA results?

Tags: pca

I have two datasets which contains the same samples, but have different measures. I wanted to test which measures were better to separate the groups in a PCA. Thus, I plotted a PCA for both datasets and observed that one dataset had a better clustering.

The question is: Is there a quantitative measure that could indicate which PCA is better?

Why I want it: I want to demonstrate using the PCA that one type of measure is better than the other to cluster the groups.

Comment: Could you explain what a "measure" is in this context?  Then, please tell us how to determine "better."  What would be the basis of comparison?  For instance, do you have information about the *true* cluster membership for comparison?

Comment: "Measure" in this case mean different experiments, I have a set o samples that I measured protein and RNA abundances; thus, I have two different datasets for the same set of samples, one containing protein measures and other RNA measures. A coworker asked if it was possible to determine which measure was the best for clustering the samples using a PCA. Visually, there is a slightly difference, but I was wondering if there was a quantitative measure that I could extract from the PCAs to confirm if one is better than the other. I don't hhave the true cluster.

Comment: In this case, it sounds like "best" would be some kind of arbitrary determination.

Answer (score 1):

PCA finds the clusters by maximizing the sample variances. So, to compare PCA the best possible quantitative measure is one that utilizes this fact.

The one I can think of right now is "the average variance of all the clusters weighted by cluster size". You can think of a better quantitative measure keeping in mind the working principle of PCA & features of your dataset.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Note that the intended meaning of "different measures" is clarified in comments to the question.